# How to analyse accuracy, hits and false alarms in e-prime?

Tags: experimental-psychology, statistics, software

It's the first time for me to do analyses with e-prime, and I have to analyse some data from an experiment. The data are, at the moment, in e-prime. I'd like to have the accuracy, the hits, and the false alarms for every subject. 
When I am in the anaylse window:

1. Accuracy: I drop the subjects into the rows, and the Target ACC into the Data window. But do I take the ACC mean or the ACC count?
2. Hits: Isn't it the same as accuracy? And, if not, what is the difference?
3. False Alarms: do I just count them? How can I make it then comparable over different tasks (some tasks have more trials than the others).

Comment: You might want to check out this [signal detection theory tutorial](http://wise.cgu.edu/sdtmod/vocab.asp) that talks about vocabulary in SDT including hits versus hit rate, and false alarm versus false alarm rates.